# How to select an attribute using nodesForXPath (NSXMLDocument)

Tags: xml, cocoa, macos, xpath

I'd like to select the attribute from an XML element within an XML document using XPath.

My XML document is an instance of NSXMLDocument. Here is an example of the XML Document:

```
<rootnode>
  <mynode myattrib="getMe"></mynode>
</rootnode>
```

My XPath is something like:

```
//mynode@myattrib
```

This should return the value "getMe" (according to: http://www.bit-101.com/xpath/ ).

When I try to do this using:

```
[xmlDoc nodesForXpath:@"//mynode@myattrib" error:&error];
```

I get the following in error:

```
NSLog(@"%@",error);
```

Output:

```
XQueryError:3 - "invalid token (@) - //mynode@myattrib" at line:1
```

What should I change to get this to work? Is the `@` symbol used in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a slash before the @, as in:

```
//mynode/@myattrib
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with XPath, what is the difference between dash and no dash? If it works in the example tool I put in the question, does that mean the tool is not working correctly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tool you used, I just looked it up in my handy "XML in a nutshell" reference. :-) All of the examples there separate each axis of an XPath query with a slash.

Comment: @Rew - XPath expressions consist of one or more location steps separated by a slash. Each step selects the set of nodes that match that portion of the expression. Once you've selected `mynode` you need an additional step to select one of its attributes, which is why the slash is necessary.